# What ROM could be used on an HTC Desire bravo with non-functioning physical buttons

Tags: custom-roms, htc-desire, rom, buttons

I have a HTC Desire (bravo). Currently I use it with the old Oxygene ROM. Basically It's fine, but the physical buttons (menu, back, home) are very hard to press. Sometimes it takes more than 5 hard presses until it reacts. There might be other ways to fix it (maybe fixing the buttons or just cleaning them?) but being a software engineer I thought that I might be able to find a ROM that can be used without those 3 physical buttons (just like the newer phones usually don't even have those physical buttons) What ROM-s are worth to look at?

Comment: You might wish to check [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Xposed framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) on a rooted device.

There are numerous modules that will enable `softkeys` on the device. Have a search in Xposed in the "Downloads" section for "softkeys".

One example [is here](http://phandroid.com/2014/06/30/android-l-xposed-module/) and it has the Android L style soft keys. In case the article goes down [here's the XDA thread with the apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-android-l-navigation-bar-t2797408)